# mule versioning on web service

Tags: web-services, mule, esb, mule-studio, mule-flow

I have the same mule webservice application with 2 different versions deployed on the same mule server. Let's call it MuleApp.1.0 and MuleApp.1.1. The flow is as simple as the example of webservice flow on mulesoft website. Their wsdl urls are different as:

```
http://www.myhost.com:25101/MuleApp.1.0/Service?wsdl
http://www.myhost.com:25101/MuleApp.1.1/Service?wsdl
```

Both of them are working as expected when the other is not deploying on the mule server. The issue happens when I having both of them deployed on the same mule server like what I used to do in WebLogic. Now I am able to access MuleApp.1.1, but when I tried to access MuleApp.1.0, I got the error as below

```
07-Mar-2013:14:52:57.142        VWILVM3667      [MuleApp.1.1].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.03
WARN    org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver     NA
No receiver found with secondary lookup on connector: connector.http.mule.default with URI key: http://www.myhost.com:25101/MuleApp.1.0/Service
```

This is supposed to be a very common versionning case. What did I miss in my config?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two different applications sharing the same HTTP port in the same Mule instance.

So what probably happens is that `MuleApp.1.0` doesn't deploy properly (check the logs), which is why there is no endpoint listening on `/MuleApp.1.0`.

Either:

- Use a different port in the two apps,
- Put both flows in a single app.
- Create a frontal app that listens on port 25101 and both `/MuleApp.1.0` and `/MuleApp.1.1` paths and that dispatches requests to `MuleApp.1.0` and `MuleApp.1.1` on private ports (say 25102 and 25103).

Comment: David

It does not make sense to me. Do you mean that I can't have 2 web applications (port 80) running on the same mule server?

Using different URLs are the only way of doing versioning on web services applications. We use the same way on other applications running on WebLogic. Are you telling me that Mule is not able to fulfill this as other application servers as WebLogic, or JBoss? If I embed mule server in a standard application server, such as JBoss, can I implement the versioning of webservice.

Comment: You can't compare Mule to JavaEE containers, they perform totally different things. Mule is able to start many HTTP servers simultaneously, but if these servers are in different apps they must be on different ports.

Comment: see I have the application deployed successfully in mule's log. no errors.


**********************************************************************
*            - - + APPLICATION + - -            * - - + STATUS + - - *
**********************************************************************
* XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-2013.5.1RC3                    * DEPLOYED           *
* XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-2013.5.1RC4                    * DEPLOYED           *
**********************************************************************

Comment: what you told me is one mule server can only have one web application lock port 80, isn't it? Any mule is not able to provide true ws versioning using different urls...

Comment: I never mentioned port 80, you did. Your question is about port 25101. Also you said two applications: are they both deployed?

Comment: both of them deployed on the same mule container. I see one work but the other not. My colleague said that both of them work on his machine, but not working at the same time. e.g. MuleApp.1.0 works this time, but not next try. I mentioned 80 because all the web apps are by default running on 80. Theriotically, no difference between port 80 and port 25101.

Comment: As David mention, you can't have 2 mule apps deployed on the same server listening to the same port.  Either you can deploy the apps on separate servers or change one one of the ports in the mule config to something other than 25101.

I would change change one of the mule-config port 25101 to another port.  e.g. 26101
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="26101"/>

Comment: Check better your logs, you will probably find something like: Port 80 already bound.

Answer (score 1):

I finally deployed my application on tomcat, and replaced http inbound endpoint with servlet inbound endpoint. I configure the web.xml with servlet class org.mule.transport.servlet.MuleReceiverServlet. Now I am able to deploy multiple applications on the same port.